# LaTeX: Input image only if it exists

Tags: graphics

I am writing a project, where I create a differing number of images that I then want to input in a latex file to print them. As I don't know how many images I will have to print, I currently have to comment images in and out prior to running the program. What I am looking for is a command, that goes something like this:
if the file exists it should run the code

```
  \begin{figure}[htbp] 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{file.pdf}
  \end{figure}
```

but if the file is non existing nothing happens and i dont have to comment out the picture manual

thanks to anyone who might be able to help me with this issue in advance

MWE:

```
\documentclass[headsepline=true, fontsize=11pt, twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{chaptername}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{figure}[htbp] 
    \caption*{caption}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Print/file}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\IfFileExists` to check if the image is present:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \IfFileExists{./duck.png}{%
          \begin{figure}[htbp] 
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{duck}
      \end{figure}
    }{}
  
    \IfFileExists{./marmot.png}{%
          \begin{figure}[htbp] 
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{marmot}
      \end{figure}
    }{}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me for some reason. i understand how it should work, thats why its especially confusing.. 2 thoughts. 1st might it be because i use \documentclass{scrreprt}? 2nd might it be becourse the file is in a subfolder (Print/file.pdf)? however it works to imput the image in a subfolde with the same code without the "iffileexists" statement

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: now i figured it out it works. thank you and have a nice day :)